# Progress bar not coming in dropzone

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

I have used dropzone for multiple file uploading, here I am facing a strange problem, I am giving my code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->webroot?>js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->webroot?>css/popup_style.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->webroot;?>css/dropzone.css" />

<script src="<?php echo $this->webroot;?>js/dropzone.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(function($){

            try {
              jQuery(".dropzone").dropzone({
                paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
                maxFilesize: 10, // MB
                maxFiles: 6,
                //autoProcessQueue: true,
                addRemoveLinks : true,
                acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif,.JPEG,.JPG,.PNG,.GIF",
                dictDefaultMessage :
                '<span class="bigger-150 bolder"><i class="icon-caret-right red"></i> Drop files</span> to upload \
                <span class="smaller-80 grey">(or click)</span> <br /> \
                <i class="upload-icon icon-cloud-upload blue icon-3x"></i>',
                dictResponseError: 'Error while uploading file!',

                //change the previewTemplate to use Bootstrap progress bars
                previewTemplate: "<div class=\"dz-preview dz-file-preview\">\n  <div class=\"dz-details\">\n    <div class=\"dz-filename\"><span data-dz-name></span></div>\n    <div class=\"dz-size\" data-dz-size></div>\n    <img data-dz-thumbnail />\n  </div>\n  <div class=\"progress progress-small progress-success progress-striped active\"><span class=\"bar\" data-dz-uploadprogress></span></div>\n  <div class=\"dz-success-mark\"><span></span></div>\n  <div class=\"dz-error-mark\"><span></span></div>\n  <div class=\"dz-error-message\"><span data-dz-errormessage></span></div>\n</div>"
              });
            } catch(e) {
              alert('Dropzone.js does not support older browsers!');
            }

            });
        </script>
<body style="margin:0px;">
<div class="popup">
    <div class="popHead">
        <!--<a href="#" class="popCross"></a>-->
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="popBody">
        <div id="dropzone">
            <form action="<?php echo $this->webroot;?>manage/multiple_latest_experience_upload" class="dropzone">
                <div class="fallback">
                    <input name="photo" id="photo" type="file" multiple="" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Now the problem is that if I use,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->webroot?>js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
```

then the properties **"maxFiles"** , **"acceptedFiles"** working properly but the progressbar is not coming.

If I remove the,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->webroot?>js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
```

JS library then the properties **"maxFiles"** , **"acceptedFiles"** not working but progressbar is coming. And when this page is loaded in a fancybox there showing a JavaScript error "Error: Dropzone already attached.". I don't understand how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

try the code below:

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("your selector",{
    // you options.
});
```

Comment: That's a very short answer, perhaps you could elaborate

Comment: **From review queue:** May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that you are using a version of [jquery](http://jquery.com/download/) that is too old. Try 1.10.2